# Assigning the "Enter Key" value to a string [C++]

Tags: c++, string

In this rather simple exercise I have to receive an user input, store said input into a string, pass the string to a function by reference and finally modify the string so that every character is "parsed" by the toupper() function.
However, should the user insert 'q' as input, the program stops saying "Bye" OR if he just presses the Enter Key, the program is supposed to say something like "Hey, this string is empty".
Now the real problem here is in the last part since my code won't manage the case where the user inputs only the Enter Key value (to be honest, even if I just text a bunch of spaces followed by the Enter Key, nothing happens)

```
 void uppercase(std::string &);

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    string ex2;
    cout << "Exercise 2" <<endl;
    while(ex2!="Bye"){
    cout << "Enter a string(q to quit): ";
    cin >> ex2;
    cout << "Was: " << ex2 << endl << "Now is: ";
    uppercase(ex2);
    }
    return 0;
} 
void uppercase(std::string &str){
    using namespace std;
    if(str[0]=='\n')
        cout <<"Empty string dude!" << endl;
    else{
        if(str.length()==1 && str[0]=='q'){ //press 'q' to exit program
            str="Bye";
            cout << str;
        }
        else{ //uppercase
            for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
                str[i]=(toupper(str[i]));
            }
            cout << str <<endl;
            }
        }
}
```

I also tried the compare() function and even to compare the whole string to null (pointless, but still worth a shot) and to the string "";

Comment: Simply check for an empty string entered: `if(str.empty())`

Comment: `cin >> ex2` cannot see enter. It is whitespace and discarded. Look into `std::getline`

Comment: @user4581301 you got that right. I used getline(cin,ex2) and modified the if statement into if(str[0]=='\0') and now it works!

Comment: Take @πάνταῥεῖ 's advice and use `empty`. One, it's easier to read and two, it could catch a few corner cases that testing for '\0' could miss. I don't think null termination was mandatory before the C++ 11 standard.

Comment: I used the empty() function AND the getline(cin,string) function (empty() didn't work without the getline() function) and it runs smoothly. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome. One last bit that may make your life easier: `std::transform`. Scroll to the bottom and you'll see how to use it to turn uppercasing a string into a quick-and-dirty one-liner: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform

Comment: Note that uppercasing one character at a time is incorrect for some languages (e.g. German).

Comment: I know, but this is an exercise to improve one's knowledge of I/O code, it's not supposed to be used for a real functioning program

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bad interpretation of your problem, trying

```
if( (str.length()==1 && str[0]=='q') || str.length() == 0)
{}
```

May help you out of the problem

Comment: *"ex2 != "Bye", is actually trying to compare references,"* Nope, and `strcmp(ex2 , "Bye")` won't compile.

Comment: After 3 correct posts, I couldn't get a single vote up, and I simply guess that people here love watching wrong answers instead of the right ones, thanks for your comment though, been a long time since I played with c/c++

Comment: That part works. As I said, the only part not working is the "Empty string dude" line.

Comment: then also try str[0] == '\r' , as this is the escape character for Carriage Return(Enter Button) in most operating system, but I don't that would help your case, as unforgiving c++ might NOT put '\r' character in the buffer upon pressing the enter button

Comment: You are part right. It might get into the buffer, but '\r' is whitespace, so OP will never see it with `operator >>`.

Comment: That's exactly what I mentioned, plus sorry for confusing white space character with escape, that was  a typo :(

Comment: *"After 3 correct posts, I couldn't get a single vote up, and I simply guess that people here love watching wrong answers instead of the right ones"* Such is life, not everything we do is well received. I have more answers with score 0 than you have posts in total. Don't worry too much about that, happens to everyone.

Comment: Thanks @Baum mi Augen, for that statement, that really meant something :)